# Terraform is asking for VPC ID even though its implied in the subnet

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following simple EC2 creating terraform script:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1" # virginia
}


resource "aws_network_interface" "network" {
  subnet_id       = "subnet-0*******"
  security_groups = ["sg-******"]

  attachment {
    instance     = aws_instance.general_instance.id
    device_index = 0
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "general_instance" {
  ami           = "ami-00874d747dde814fa" # unbutu server
  instance_type = "m5.2xlarge"
  key_name      = "my-key"
  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    volume_size           = 500
    tags                  = { Name = "Root Volume" }
  }
  # user_data = file("startup.sh") # file directive can install stuff
  tags = {
    Name = "General"
  }
}
```

I get the following:

```
Error: Error launching source instance: VPCIdNotSpecified: No default VPC for this user. GroupName is only supported for EC2-Classic and default VPC.
```

I find this odd because the classic flow is to make a VPC, make a subnet and then make a network interface. However, I have a VPC I want to use that is associated with the subnet I'm using. So I'm wondering whey it's asking for a VPC id if I have it associated with the subnet I'm requesting.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out already.

```
resource "aws_instance" "general_instance" {
  ami           = "ami-00874d747dde814fa" # unbutu server
  instance_type = "m5.2xlarge"
  key_name      = "EC2-foundry"

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.network.id
    device_index         = 0
  }

  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    volume_size           = 500
    tags                  = { Name = "Foundry Root Volume" }
  }
  # user_data = file("startup.sh") # file directive can install stuff
  tags = {
    Name = "Foundry General"
  }
}
```

network interface must be attached in the aws resource